# how to get the second element in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried to get only the hexadecimal value of my array.
I have this code and so far I have been able to print all the values, but I want just the hexa.

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string[,] bgColor = {
            {"White","FFFFFF"},
            {"Green","1CAE1E"},
            {"Blue","201CAE"},
            {"Red","AE221C"},
            {"Pink","AE1C81"},
            {"Orange","AE771C"},
            {"Yellow","AEAE1C"},
            {"Violet","5D1479"},
            {"Black","000000"}};
    
      foreach (string i in bgColor)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two-dimensional array, so you need to iterate by the first dimension and get the second value from each "line"

```
  for (var i=0; i<bgColor.GetLength(0);i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(bgColor[i,1]);
  }
```

`GetLength` above allows to get the size of specified dimension (0 in this sample, i.e. number of "rows")